# Substituion of a Let(name, bound, body)-Expression (pseudo code)

Tags: pseudocode, substitution, evaluation, let, shadowing

one of my tasks in my studies is to consider which of those possibilities of that pseudo-code is right. I have to take care about variable shadowing and variable capturing.
Here's following task:

```
(let y 3 (let y x (let x 1 (* y x))))
```

and i have to choose one of the answers:

```
(* 1 3)
(* 1 1)
(* 3 1)
(* 3 3)
(* y 1)
(* 3 x)
(* x 1)
(* y x)
```

Maybe you could help me out there:)

I already thought about that problem and i already got an example exercise in study-script but that task was a way easier and there's not explain how to solve that expression step-by-step.

My answer would be: (* x 1), because I tried to follow the nesting of these expression through the outer to the inner one, which leads to that solution.
But if try to write a programm in a actual language it throw me a exception that the variable x isn't bounded and if I ask chatGPT he give me multiple different answers but the most frequent one was:   (* 3 1), so I'm really not sure.....

Comment: Pseudo code is intended to be absolutely clear to the reader. This isn't. Not good pseudo code in my opinion.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's the code that our university gave us. Unfortunately, I can't say any more about that...

Comment: Where is the documentation of this pseudo code? What do the parentheses mean, what do the symbols mean, what does `*` mean? Without meaning this code is just a series of characters.

Comment: The basic arithmetic operations apply as in other programming languages, with the exception that only two expressions can be linked.

Thats the abstract syntax of that code: 

`Exp ::= Double (Num) | 
(+ Exp Exp) (Plus) | (* Exp Exp) (Mult) | 
(/ Exp Exp) (Div) | (let Symbol Exp Exp) (Let) | 
Symbol`

you can imagine that this is a nesting of declarations on immutable variables combined with basic arithmetic. I'm sorry for this incomprehensible description but I'm new here and trying to learn.

Comment: OK, that is *syntax*, but what about *semantics*? Is there assignment? Does an assignment create an alias? Can expressions consist of unresolved symbols? What then happens in expressions? Etc... etc...